# Dividing page into sections by height, section not expanding to full specified height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code. I divided the whole page by height, 20%, 50%, 30%;

But for some reason the table in the `SECOND SECTION` is not getting the whole 50%. only maybe 10%. It is resided in a row-fluid. If I put overflow hidden, only the header will be visible.

css:

```
  .body-wrapper{
    height:100%;
  }
  .body-wrapper > fieldset div:nth-of-type(1){
    height:20%;
  }
  .body-wrapper > fieldset div:nth-of-type(2){
    height:40%;
  }
  .body-wrapper > fieldset div:nth-of-type(3){
    height:30%;
  }
```

html:

```
    <div class = "main-Frame container-fluid"> <!-- mid section -->
      <div class="well row-fluid" >
        <div class="body-wrapper">
          <fieldset>

            <div> <!-- FIRST SECTION -->
              <legend>User Profile</legend>
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-2 text-right">User Name
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" >
                  <input style="width:90%;"type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 text-right">User Email
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">kkk@gmail.com
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                  <input type="checkbox"/>Active
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> <!-- END OF FIRST SECTION -->

            <div> <!-- SECOND SECTION -->
              <legend>Application Defaults</legend>
              <div class = "container-fluid" style="height:100%;">
                <div class="row-fluid"  style="height:100%;">
                  <div class="col-md-10" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="table-responsive user-table">

                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>App</th>
                          <th>Type</th>
                          <th>Setting</th>
                          <th>check</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>first</td>
                          <td>first</td>
                          <td>first</td>
                          <td>first</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div> <!-- END of SECOND section -->


            <div> <!-- LAST section -->
              <legend>ChangePassword</legend>
            </div> <!-- END of footer section -->

          </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem here is that your CSS selectors are too broad - the selector `.body-wrapper > fieldset div:nth-of-type(1)` matches both the intended target (the first `<div>` directly under the fieldset, and the more deeply nested `<div class="table-responsive user-table">`. (On all preceding elements that also match, you've used inline styles to force their heights to 100%, so they don't exhibit the same problem behaviour.)

To address this issue, simply narrow down the range of elements matched by your selectors by increasing their specificity - for example, target only immediate child `<div>` elements under the fieldset, rather than all descendant ones:

```css
.body-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.body-wrapper > fieldset > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 20%;
}
.body-wrapper > fieldset > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 40%;
}
.body-wrapper > fieldset > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 30%;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.